# How can I load google ads to a fragment in onCreate() function when I already use setContentView() with a different layout in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

Is there a way I can have two different setContentView() calls in onCreate() or is there a way I can separate them? I already use setContentView() to load my navigation drawer and toolbar and I don't know how to restructure the code to accommodate it to also include ads.

I am new to android development so I might be missing something very trivial.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
lateinit var mAdView : AdView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    //Initialize fab listener and SnackBar onClick
    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Here goes Nothing!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)


    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home)

    
    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    
    //this is the line where I get an error
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home)
    
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewHomeFragment)
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
    
}
/**This creates the options menu**/
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}}
```

If you have any advice on what is wrong with this structure or how I can improve it I would be incredibly thankful.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is the line where I get an error
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home)
```

There is no need to add another layout to call ads. Use `setContentView()` once, which you have done already after calling `onCreate()`. Make sure that your adview is added to your xml layout file (`activity_main.xml` in this case). Call it from the `MainActivity`. Check out this for ad implementation - [Banner Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#kotlin)

If you want to ad in fragment, then add adview to your fragment layout and call it from the fragment code. The code that you provide does not load fragment. Check these example on how to load fragment - [Add a fragment](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-create-and-add-fragment/#3)